# Error while import plot_spatial_weights in Python

Tags: python, pysal

I am trying to import `plot_spatial_weights` from `pysal.viz.splot.libpysal`

this what I am doing

`from pysal.viz.splot.libpysal import plot_spatial_weights`

and I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysal.viz'
```

Comment: have you done `pip install pysal`?

Comment: yes, i can import `pysal`

Comment: Which version of pysal do you have? The issue might be there.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem occurred due to pysal 2.0, maybe switching to pysal 1.14 will wipe out this error. Check this topic: https://github.com/darribas/gds18/issues/8